# What is the macros of multiple values for INSERT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO reports (id, date, message) 
   VALUES ($1, $2, $3) 
      RETURNING id
```

Is it possible to replace `($1, $2, $3)` with something simpler, like `?` or `*`? It's a bit frustrating - to type in all values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM VALUES()` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO reports (id, date, message) 
SELECT col1, col2, 'const_value'
FROM (VALUES (...,...),
             (...,...)) s(col1, col2, ...,coln)
RETURNING id;
```

---

Sample demo:

```
CREATE TABLE reports(id SERIAL, daten DATE, message TEXT);

INSERT INTO reports ( daten, message) 
SELECT  col2, 'const_value'
FROM (VALUES ('2019-01-01'::date),
             ('2019-01-02'::date)) s(col2)
RETURNING id;

SELECT * FROM reports;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=80d86f9e18d330f91347f46425bd176f)**

Comment: I was expecting something like `VALUES (?)`
Guess it's that case when shorter approach just does not exists.